# how to get key from json

Tags: json, ionic3

i am developing `Hybrid` messaging app using `ionic-3`. i am getting json data from firebase and i want to get key from JSON. JSON data is as like below image and i have marked key with red round which i want to get.
Does anybody know how to get key from below JSON data?
Thank you.

> image:

[image]

Comment: you need only keys of the object. Or want to take value of the keys

Comment: i need only keys of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using Object.keys to retrieve keys array :

```
yourObject = {
    "34_11": {
        "152445455455": {
            "message": "Hello",
            "receiver_id": "sandip1"
        }
    },
    "35_34": {
        "1524454558421": {
            "message": "Hello2",
            "receiver_id": "sandip2"
        }
    }
}

Object.keys(yourObject);
```

This would yield :

```
["34_11", "35_34"]
```